# Multiplication and addition, but in a weird way.

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

*'calculate the product of x and y by accumulating the sum of x copies of y'*

I'm stumped, what is it this exercise actually wants me to do? Express $x$ * $y$ as something else? I'm allowed to use an algorithm (*i.e. pseudocode/math*) instead of algebra, if anyone can help.

Comment: It wants you to write $x \cdot y = \underbrace {y+y+\dots+y} _ {x ~ \text{times}}$.

Comment: Thanks Karolis, that helped me figure it out. I put it as 0+Y(x) = Z.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the comment what the question is asking you to do.

Here is the pseudocode...

1. Initialize  a variable 'sum' to zero.

2.Initialize the values if x and y or you can even take them as inputs from the user.

3.start a loop

```
sum = sum + x
```

Repeat this y number of times.

4. Display sum as product of x and y.

You can interchange the third step with this

3. Start a loop

   sum = sum + y

   Repeat this x number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I would write an algorithm in pseudocode using a FOR loop to add $y$ to a variable (initialised as zero) $x$ times.